# Determining the square of a $\lim \sup$

Tags: real-analysis

From number 5 of [this released exam](https://math.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/pages/F03_Final_Exam-D.Sarason.pdf):

> Let $(s_n)$ be a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $a = \lim\inf s_n$ and $b = \lim \sup s_n$. Show that $\lim \sup s^2_n = \max\{a^2, b^2\}$.

I am having trouble reasoning about this. I want to say something along the lines of:

$$\lim\inf s_n^2 = (\lim\inf s_n)(\lim\inf s_n) = a^2$$

and:

$$\lim\sup s_n^2 = (\lim\sup s_n)(\lim\sup s_n) = b^2$$

Given that the $\lim \inf$ and $\lim \sup$ are both positive, similarly if they are not positive then the inequality should be flipped somehow because of this property:

$$\inf(S) = -\sup(-S)$$

this would then allow me to conlude it is either $a^2$ or $b^2$. Furthermore, it is clear that it should be the max of the two. I am unsure about how I should go about how I can rigorously convey these properties. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't say that the lim inf and lim sup are positive. (That's why you have to take the maximum of $a^2$ and $b^2$.) ... This is just unravelling the definitions: You have a subsequence of $(s_n)$ that converges to $a$ and converges to $b$. Can you find a subsequence of $(s_n^2)$ that converges to $a^2$? $b^2$? Why can't any subsequence of $(s_n^2)$ converge to anything bigger than the max of $a^2$ and $b^2$?

Comment: @ChristopherCarlHeckman: I used your hint and came up with a solution which I posted below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By Christopher Carl Heckman's comment:

Since $\lim \inf (s_n) = a$ and $\lim \sup (s_n) = b$, this implies there is are subsequences $(s_{n_{k}})$ and $(s_{n_{k'}})$ such that:

$$ \lim (s_{n_k}) = a$$

and:

$$ \lim (s_{n_{k'}}) = b$$

Hence:

$$ \lim (s_{n_k})^2 = a^2$$

and:

$$ \lim (s_{n_{k'}})^2 = b^2$$

Now assume that there is a subsequence in $(s_n)^2$ that converges to a value greater than $a^2$ or $b^2$. Then this sequence can be decomposed into the subsequence $(s_{n_{k^*}})$ where $(s_{n_{k^*}})$ is a subsequence of $(s_n)^2$. In the case $(s_{n_{k^*}})$ doesn't converge, I can ensure there is a subsequence by the Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem that does converge. The sequence then has a limiting value $c$ such that:

$$a \leq c \leq b$$

We consider cases:

1. $|a| < |b|$: then $c^2 < b^2$.
2. $|a| > |b|$: then $c^2 < a^2$.
3. $|a| = |b|$: then $c^2 < b^2$ and $c^2 < a^2$.

Hence $\lim \sup s^2_n = \max\{a^2, b^2\}$.

Comment: The first part is okay; the second part needs some work. (What if $a=-1$ and $b=4$? Can't you possibly have $c=3$?) ... You should probably break this into the cases  $|b| \ge |a|$ and $|b| \le |a|$. (They're handled similarly, of course.)

Comment: If $|b| \ge |a|$, then you want to show that no subsequence of $(s_n^2)$ converges to anything larger than $b^2$. If you have such a subsequence $(s'_n)$, then there are either infinitely many positive terms or infinitely many negative terms. (Why?) If there are infinitely many positive terms, then that subsequence converges to something greater than $b$ (which is a contradiction); if there are infinitely many negative terms, then that subsequence converges to a number less than $-b$; but $-b<a$ (why?), so you get a contradiction that way as well.

Comment: @ChristopherCarlHeckman: Ok, changed the cases.

Comment: There's still an issue here. You're picking a convergent subsequence of $(s_n^2)$, and then taking the corresponding subsequence $t_n$ of $(s_n)$. What if some of the terms in $t_n$ are positive, and some are negative? You might have a subsequence of $t_n$ that converges to $b$, and a subsequence that converges to $-b$, which means $t_n$ doesn't converge at all.

Comment: One more nitpick: You can only conclude that $a\le c \le b$; you won't get strict inequality.

Comment: In the case that $t_n$ doesn't converge, I can choose a convergent subsequence by the Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: ... Or ... You could find the lim sup of $t_n$ ... I think you've pretty much got it now; I'm signing off.

Comment: @ChristopherCarlHeckman: Ok, thanks!

Comment: @Dair. If a subsequence $(s^2_{n_k})_k$ converges to $ l^2$ with $ 0<l$ and $l^2>\max (a^2,b^2)$  then either there are infinitely many $  k$ for which $s_{n_k}>(l+|b|)/2>|b|\geq b$  (contradicting the def'n of $b$) or there are infinitely many $k$ for which $s_{n_k}<-(l+|a|)/2<-|a|\leq a$  (contradicting the def'n of $a$).